# Custom password ValidationMessageFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I'm trying to create a custom password validation for an authentication system depending on what the password settings are set to using MVC.

In the admin area of the system, the user can choose which settings the password has to adhere to. I want the validation message to reflect that and only show when a password has been entered incorrectly however at present it shows all the time.

This is my view:

```
@model Domain.Authentication.Users.RegisterDTO

@helper passwordPolicySpecs()
{
    Services.Settings.Interfaces.ISettingsService _service = Core.Context.Engine.Resolve<Services.Settings.Interfaces.ISettingsService>();
    string passwordWarning = "Password invalid. Password must contain: ";
    passwordWarning = (_service.GetSettingValue<Services.Authentication.Policies.PasswordPolicySettings, bool>(x => x.PasswordMustBeMinimumLength)) ? passwordWarning + ("At least " + _service.GetSettingValue<Services.Authentication.Policies.PasswordPolicySettings, int>(x => x.PasswordLength).ToString() + " letters. ") : passwordWarning + "";
    passwordWarning = (_service.GetSettingValue<Services.Authentication.Policies.PasswordPolicySettings, bool>(x => x.PasswordMustContainANumber)) ? passwordWarning + "A number. " : passwordWarning + "";
    passwordWarning = (_service.GetSettingValue<Services.Authentication.Policies.PasswordPolicySettings, bool>(x => x.PasswordMustContainASpecialCharacter)) ? passwordWarning + "A special character. " : passwordWarning + "";
    passwordWarning = (_service.GetSettingValue<Services.Authentication.Policies.PasswordPolicySettings, bool>(x => x.PasswordMustContainLowerCase)) ? passwordWarning + "A lower case letter. " : passwordWarning + "";
    passwordWarning = (_service.GetSettingValue<Services.Authentication.Policies.PasswordPolicySettings, bool>(x => x.PasswordMustContainUpperCase)) ? passwordWarning + "An upper case letter. " : passwordWarning + "";
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, passwordWarning, new { @class = "text-danger" })
}

<div class="reset-password-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            <h2>@Core.Helpers.ResourceHelpers.Get("Register")</h2>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Authentication", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RegistrationForm" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <fieldset>
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        <dd>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Core.Helpers.ResourceHelpers.Get("EmailAddress") } })
                        </dd>

                        <dd>
                            @passwordPolicySpecs()
                            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Core.Helpers.ResourceHelpers.Get("Password") })
                        </dd>

                        <dd class="padding-top-10">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Core.Helpers.ResourceHelpers.Get("ConfirmPassword") })
                        </dd>

                    </dl>

                    <p class="register-btn">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) <!--Fill in all fields error-->
                        <input type="submit" value="@Core.Helpers.ResourceHelpers.Get("Register")" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```